# I know that $y=A\sin (kx-vt)$ that $y$ displacement is Transverse wave. Now how is that for Longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves

I know that $y=A\sin (kx-vt)$ that $y$ displacement is Transverse wave. now how is that for Longitudinal wave?

Comment: hi, I see you are new user, we need you to edit the question and add more information so it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: Wave equation is something ,some sort of energy transfer without actual moment of a particle,in longitudinal wave ,particle of vibrating make neighbouring particle to vibrate

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what bothers you but I guess you simply need to name your displacement variable with a different name from the coordinate names. You could for instance name  $v$ the displacement component in the $y$ direction and $u$  the displacement component in the $x$ direction. Then $u \cos (\omega t -kx)$ would be a longitudinal wave, and $v \cos (\omega t -kx)$ would be a transverse wave.